# How to check if a substring is in any array value in Postgres?

Tags: string, postgresql, string-matching

So I have the following use case:

I have three values `street_a`, `number_a` and `address_list` of type `varchar` like this:

```
address_a = 'Main Street'
number_a = '4'
address_list = 'Lower Street 6;Main Street 3,4,5'
```

Now I would like to return a `TRUE` when I check the concatenated  strings of `street_a` and `number_a` (`Main Street 4`) as it is part of `address_list`. I hoped that the following would work:

```
SELECT 
    lower(REPLACE(street_a, ' ', '')) || '%,' || number_a || ',%' 
    LIKE ANY 
    (string_to_array(lower(REPLACE(address_list, ' ','')), ';'))
```

However, the `%` signs in a `LIKE` statement are only applied when on the right side of the check. When on the left side they are just concatenated to the strings...

**EDIT**

And because of other cases like

```
address_list = 'Main Street 1,2;Lower Street 4'
```

I cannot do

```
SELECT 
    lower(REPLACE(address_list, ' ',''))
    LIKE
    lower(REPLACE(street_a, ' ', '')) || '%' || number_a || '%'
```

Is there a way to return `TRUE` for my case here?

Comment: The underlying problem is storing lists as CSV fields. Store each address as its own row in its own table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that this is not the best way to store addresses, or do lookups. There's a ton of complexities in addresses, for which this approach is not well suited.  I'd advise against going this route at all.  However, if you're **forced** to do so, then I think using a [regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) may be a better approach than a `LIKE` expression.

*Note:  I'm not addressing the possibility that the street or number could possibly contain characters that should be escaped, or many other scenarios, but this code "could" work under certain circumstances.*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION address_match(street_a text, number_a text, address_list text) RETURNS BOOLEAN LANGUAGE plpgsql AS     
$$ 
declare
  pattern text := replace(street_a, ' ', '') || '(([0-9]+,)*)' || number_a || '(,.*)?$'; 
  result bool;
begin
  with a as (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(replace(address_list,  ' ', ''), ';')) as address) 
  select exists(select a.address from a where a.address ~* pattern) into result;
  return result;
end;
$$;
```

Some quick test scenarios ...

```
postgres=# select address_match('Main Street', '3', 'Lower Street 6;Main Street 3,4,5');
 address_match 
---------------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select address_match('Main Street', '4', 'Lower Street 6;Main Street 3,4,5');
 address_match 
---------------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select address_match('Main Street', '5', 'Lower Street 6;Main Street 3,4,5');
 address_match 
---------------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select address_match('maiN StreeT', '3', 'Lower Street 6;Main Street 3,4,5');
 address_match 
---------------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select address_match('Main Street', '33', 'Lower Street 6;Main Street 3,4,5');
 address_match 
---------------
 f
(1 row)

postgres=# select address_match('Main Street', '45', 'Lower Street 6;Main Street 3,4,5');
 address_match 
---------------
 f
(1 row)

postgres=# select address_match('maiN StreeT', '1', 'Lower Street 6;Main Street 3,4,5');
 address_match 
---------------
 f
(1 row)

postgres=# select address_match('Lower    StreeT', '6', 'Lower Street 6;Main Street 3,4,5');
 address_match 
---------------
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# select address_match('Lower    StreeT', '3', 'Lower Street 6;Main Street 3,4,5');
 address_match 
---------------
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great! And yes, I am forced to this strategy as this is the data how it arrives from the frontend at the moment (hopefully will be changed soon!). I store my addresses more efficiently ;)

Comment: I just think that `'(,.*)?$'` should be `'(.*)?$'` because if I would check `address_match('Main Street', '5', 'Main Street 5;Lower Street 6')` it would return `f`

Comment: I added the comma in the expression so that it would not match on something that just begins with 5, like 50, 51, etc.  The '?' makes that group optional, so even if there are no other numbers, I believe it should still work.  That scenario is in one of the "Lower Street" tests I listed.

Comment: Ah right. Then it should be `([,;].*)?$`?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> address_list = 'Lower Street 6;Main Street 3,4,5'
> ```

It is very inefficient and complicated to store lists like this in SQL. Instead, store each address in its own row.

```
create table addresses (
  address text not null
);

insert into addresses values
  ('Lower Street 6'), ('Main Street 3'), ('Main Street 4'), ('Main Street 5');
```

Now it's a simple select.

```
select 1
from addresses
where lower(address) = lower(street_a) || ' ' || number_a
```

You can index `lower(address)` to make it run quickly and avoid duplicates.

```
create unique index lower_case_address ON addresses ((lower(address)));
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f8ff1f33aba31934fd9ad44c45a75fba).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I am forced to this strategy as the address list is not something that is stored in my database (I store addresses more efficiently) but it is how the data arrives from the frontend. However, for now the reply by @NullPointerException solved my use case

Comment: @JoeBe What is the reason you're doing it in Postgres? This sort of work is easier to do in a regular programming language. [If you edit the question with your full circumstances, you might get a better solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The reason is that this is the current situation of our stack right now. So I think my question was formulated in the exact way as I needed it. And the solution I got from here was perfect for my specific use-case